# Master Page Error

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have created a master page and attached other pages to, and it looks fine. But when I run it, it gives me the following error message:

```
*Parse Error Message: The file'/projectname/MasterPage.vb' does not exist*
```

I don't know why, because the master page is there. It continues to the next line and says:

```
*Line1 <% Master Language="VB" CodeFile="MasterPage.master.vb" Inherits=MasterPage" %>*
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

check on solution explorer for this file MasterPage.vb maybe you deleted. Or just click twice anywhere on your file MasterPage.master on design view if it shows you the file MasterPage.vb check that your class name is Partial Class MasterPage